# Iterative Topological search (DFS)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

How can an iterative dfs topological sort be accomplished on a directed acyclic graph?

Here is a vertex

```
class Vertex {
  List<Vertex> adj = new ArrayList<>();
  char val;

  Vertex(char val) {this.val = val;}
}
```

A recursive solution is straightforward using a set to mark visited nodes and a stack to order the vertices:

```
List<Vertex> sortRecursive(List<Vertex> vertices) {
  Deque<Vertex> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
  Set<Vertex> visited = new HashSet<>();
  for (Vertex Vertex : vertices) {
    if (visited.contains(Vertex)) continue;
    sortRecursiveHelper(stack, visited, Vertex);
  }
  List<Vertex> output = new ArrayList<>();
  while (!stack.isEmpty()) output.add(stack.removeFirst());
  return output;
}

void sortRecursiveHelper(Deque<Vertex> stack, Set<Vertex> visited, Vertex vertex) {
  visited.add(vertex);
  for (Vertex vv : vertex.adj) {
    if (visited.contains(vv)) continue;
    sortRecursiveHelper(stack, visited, vv);
  }
  stack.addFirst(vertex);
}
```

This is a driver:

```
Vertex a = new Vertex('A');
Vertex b = new Vertex('B');
Vertex c = new Vertex('C');
Vertex d = new Vertex('D');
Vertex e = new Vertex('E');
Vertex f = new Vertex('F');
Vertex g = new Vertex('G');


a.adj.add(c);
b.adj.add(c);
b.adj.add(e);
c.adj.add(d);
d.adj.add(f);
e.adj.add(f);
f.adj.add(g);

List<Vertex> output = sortRecursive(Arrays.asList(d, a, e, g, f, b, c));
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508765/how-to-implement-depth-first-search-for-graph-with-non-recursive-aprroach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a stack of active vertices and the index of the first child that hasn't been processed yet to simulate recursion:

```
while stack.non_empty()
    if stack.top().second == graph[stack.top().first].size:
        // We pop the vertex here, so we add it to the answer list
        sorted_order.add(stack.top().first)
        stack.pop_back()
    else:
        // We get the next child and move increase the index
        // so that it points to the unprocessed child
        next_child = graph[stack.top().first][stack().top().second]
        stack.top().second += 1
        // If we need to go to the child, we push it to the
        // stack instead of making a recursive call
        if not next_child is visited:
            mark next_child as visited
            stack.push(pair(next_child, 0))
```